# Reconstructing a graph from shortest paths information

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Given an undirected unweighted graph $G(V, E)$, there is an efficient algorithm to find the shortest paths between every pair of nodes. I am interested in the reverse problem, we want to reconstruct the original graph given the shortest distances between every pair of nodes.

**Reconstruction from shortest paths**

**INPUT**: An integer matrix $A$

**Question**: Is there a graph $G(V, E)$ such that $A_{(i,j)} $ is the shortest distance between nodes $i$ and $j$.

> What is known about the complexity of this problem? Is it solvable by a polynomial-time algorithm? Is it NP-complete?

Comment: Note that $uv$ is an edge of $G$ if and only if the distance between $u$ and $v$ is $1$.  Thus, you know all the edges, and hence the entire graph (in polynomial-time).

Comment: A more interesting question can be obtained if $A$ is not bound to contain distances between ALL pairs of vertices, but just between the vertices in some subset of $V(G)$.

Comment: @monkeymaths Yes, another variant is restricting A to contain only distances greater than 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is solvable in polynomial-time.  Given a $V \times V$  distance matrix $A$, let $G$ be the graph with vertex set $V$, where $uw \in E(G)$ if and only if $A_{uw}=1$.  Note that $G$ is the only possible graph that has shortest distance matrix $A$.  Now just compute all the shortest distances between all pairs of nodes in $G$ (this can be done in polynomial-time by [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)), and check that the distances agree with those in $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I  guess an interesting problem is restricting $A$ to contain only distances greater than 2 . Should I add this variant to the post or should I post a new question?

Comment: You're welcome. I think the standard protocol is to ask a new question. You can link to this question in the description of the new question if you like

Comment: I'm not sure this is POLY since this seems to require looping through all possible (connected) graphs on V vertices...